# run commands using default.nix file

Tags: shell, elixir, elixir-mix, nixos

I've got the following `default.nix` file:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
   pullapiEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation {
     name = "pullapi";
     buildInputs = [ elixir ];
   };
 }
```

Which is great, and works with `nix-shell` inside my repo, however how
do run I commands during the shell setup? I'd like to run

```
mix deps.get
mix test
```

upon each `nix-shell` execution.

Comment: `nix-shell` have `--command` and `--run` flag. Please take a look by running `nix-shell --help`. Don't really sure if this is what you want.

Comment: thanks, I'm looking for a nix expression however, to automate the commands

Comment: I see, I think you want to use [shellHook](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#description-13).

Comment: Thanks, that worked - please may you post that as an answer?

Comment: It's good to know the problem is solved, you also can [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own question on how you solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per **wizzup**'s comment, this was solved using `shellHook`:

```
#default.nix
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
   pullapiEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation {
     name = "pullapi";
     buildInputs = [ elixir ];
     shellHook = ''
     mix deps.get
     mix compile
     mix test
     '';
   };
}
```